# why is syntax interesting?

Tags: syntax, historical-linguistics, sociolinguistics

I hear a lot the argument that "language is just a way of communication, therefore it is not "really" interesting to waste the time on studying aspects such as syntax, rather the truly interesting thing is how it is encoded in the brain"

Although this is a very personal opinion which reflects the taste of the speaker, I hear it so much that I was wondering how you would react to such a statement?

Comment: Syntax is our best guess as to how it's encoded in the brain.

Comment: _Being interested_ is a personal characteristic, not a universal one.

Comment: @ColinFine, it's circular reasoning, but not a paradox that there is, objectively speaking, subjectivity. I'm voting reopen because I spent effort on my answer

Comment: The question seems to take syntax and brain phenomena as alternate theories of language.  But that is nonsense.  Rather, formulating a syntax is the means by which we advance our understanding of brain phenomena.

Comment: @ColinFine I am well aware that this is a personal opinion (as I also mentioned in my question). I was wondering how people from the linguistics "community" think about this...

Comment: @LukeSawczak what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Em_ Similar to vectory's point: it takes little data to see that the brain must encode structures for linguistic phenomena (as opposed to a huge set of unanalyzed physical imprints of waveforms...). Linguistics posits structures that fit the data. Compare a computer file, say an image. The bits that make it up (perhaps like neurons) encode various structures, say headings, metadata, content. Studying the structures is studying the encoding system. Maybe you're only interested in the actual 0s and 1s or the physical brain. But those are only interesting because they encode said structures.

Answer (score 4):

The underlying premise (obviously false when you reveal it) is that all people in the room (world?) have the same goal, so what is "interesting" versus "uninteresting" is the same for everybody. If you limit this to a room full of brain scientists, it might be true that those people have greater interest in knowing  how language is encoded in the brain than they would in knowing what the cross-linguistically valid generalizations about syntax are. If you are in a room full of syntacticians, the opposite could be the case (it depends on the type of syntax). On a global level, neither question is interesting.

In that room of brain scientists, you might have a number of people who have equal interest in knowledge of both linguistic systems and brain structure. For example, syntax raises questions and presents data that an account of brain structure has to have answers to, since an explanatory theory of brain structure not only lists the parts and how they are assembled, it explains how the brain does what it does.

The quoted dismissive comment is an instance of the fallacy of incomplete reductionism. High level system X is "superficial" and uninteresting, compared to "deeper" causal explanation W. Fine, but W itself is uninterestingly superficial, we need to get at what *explains* brain structure. So one can abandon interest in "superficial" phenomena such as syntax, or brain structure, and instead focus on quantum mechanics and string theory. And yet in doing so, one has abandoned the search for knowledge – there is no quantum-mechanical explanation for Germanic (+Kashmiri) V2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

One can scientifically have logical notions and models on language, that is *knowledge*.

"How it is encoded in the brain" is still a large unknown, not really a denotable calculatory model.

One might argue that language is just a systematic input and output of the brain processes.
But that would be the same argument as calling biology less relevant than the more interesting highly complex chemical/energetic processes that cause life.

We can only study the reachable, and a product shows its creator or its creator's logic.

So: the unknown might be more interesting *in the future*, but a criminal investigation also starts with left prints. *At the current moment* occupying oneself with a chaotical unknown is utter insanity.

*You certainly can find a better wording than my answer.*

Answer (score 0):

This question is definitely asking about opinion. Its unwritten premisses is that syntax is interesting, to some at least. In my opinion, you should rather ask "what is it?".

Very abstractly speaking, syntax is part of the formal definition of the grammar of a language. As such, syntax is one part of the definition of language.

Obviously, if one tries to find language, in the brain or anywhere else, one needs a working definition it.

Ironically, one doesn't have to be able to verbalize the definition, just to use it, but one has to use it in order to be able to verbalize it.

I. Therefore, syntax is interesting if neuro linguistics is. But Vice versa, syntax might be interesting without talking about neurons, and neurons might be interesting even if language isn't the goal.

a) In one perspective, syntax < neuro // that is, it's less interesting

if and only if neuro science were a strict super set

if syntax basically describes how we understand our language, but is devoid of meaning itself; that is, one might hypothesise in principle that it describes our neurons

b) one might even say grammatical syntax isn't necessary for language: there's null syntax in "Mama!"; However, there's context, and we might expect a syntax of actions, if take the very broad definition of language, that is any communication, willful act, etc--that's a matter of philosophy, especially as regards free will, but it is not the reigning conception in linguistics, which necessarily has to limit the scope of inquiry. The only additional question in philosophy that I can think of comin from increasing acces to the brain concerns ethics and has not much bearing on linguistics, so far.

II. On the other hand, neuro science isn't an end in itself; it's just a means to an end.

a1) There's no change in the perceived value of syntax. It's always been understood that it is also just a means to an end. There is no competition.

a2) Well, there is competition, and socio-linguistics would have a field day with the remarks that you haven submitted. Alas, I am not sure of the extent that it relies on syntax.

b) Results from finding the language homunculus and understanding of its pertuberations will surely solves outstanding problems in syntax and improve our use of it. So there's no strict hierarchy.

c) If that potential does have ethical implications, then improved syntax might be needed to communicate those, or perhaps even solve them and other problems, especially if philosophy is just a lot of bickering over how to say things in a way that can be commonly understood and used, although the basic problems are already understood and frequently solvedwithout going onto the metalevel. That would be abstract nonsense, I think, therefore I'm writing it down. One trivial example is simple language, e.g. the *Einfache Sprache* projects in German; I say trivial because at the moment it's mostly a matter of style and other rhethoric elements in official texts to the public; but the research agenda is to improve understanding, overall.

III. Syntax and semantix form a duality, that can't be strictly separated. Semantics is well interesting, I would say.

**Conclusion:** For the time being, the problem is not whether *syntax is interesting* (or important), but still *how*--not *how interesting*; just *how?*

PS: You might as well say: *Talking about music is like fishing over architecture* (paraphrasing Frank Zappa).

Comment: I love that you paraphrased Zappa :) Thanks for the comment, you raised many interesting points here.